# Secure communications with SSL only used for log in?

Tags: security, http, ssl

I've read that you can't really secure your API when using SSL only for logging in, but it seems to me that something like [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) could enable it:

- Client connects via SSL, sends credentials, and receives a session ID cookie, as well as session secret.
- API calls are made via plain old HTTP/whatever, but include a timestap + nonce, and a hash of (payload+timestamp+nonce+secret) that can be regenerated by the server to verify client possession of the secret and prevent replays.

What am I missing that makes this insecure?

Comment: Below link contains your answer. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/is-using-hmac-to-transmit-a-password-ok

Comment: That link seems to be about logging in without SSL, but I'm interested in using SSL to establish a session and retrieve a session secret, and then using that secret to sign plaintext payloads.

Comment: @Sophistifunk: So you want to ensure integrity/authenticity, but not confidentiality? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, basically. For things where it doesn't really matter if somebody knows what you're doing, so long as nobody but you can do it :)

Answer (score 0):

sites that use HTTPS only for password entry and then fall back to HTTP are vulnerable to numerous attacks, including session cookie eavesdropping (aka Firesheep) and MITM attacks. That's why those sites are insecure and security folks recommend using sitewide SSL; sites that are using HTTPS only for password entry are "doing it wrong"

Comment: Sorry But I dont understand your comment